# Query Syntax in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, ansi-sql

How can we convert below query in Oracle to Hive compatible ANSI SQL syntax?
Please help.

`SELECT C.BUSINESS_UNIT_CA, (SELECT C1.DESCR FROM HIVE_TABLE_C1 C1 WHERE C.BUSINESS_UNIT_CA = C1.BUSINESS_UNIT) AS CA_BU_DESCR FROM HIVE_TABLE_C C`

Comment: Just a comment, but the original query is ANSI SQL compliant! (According to https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT C.BUSINESS_UNIT_CA, C1.DESCR AS CA_BU_DESCR 
 FROM HIVE_TABLE_C C
      LEFT JOIN HIVE_TABLE_C1 C1 ON C.BUSINESS_UNIT_CA = C1.BUSINESS_UNIT
```